# Is it possible to access a parent doc field over a firestore collectionGroup query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

**My question is not about accessing a field of a parent doc when you have the document snapshot.**

I am trying to perform a query which has to access a field of a parent doc, for example, with this NoSQL structure:

```
(C) users/
   (D) userId/
       -premium: false
       -random: uuid.v4 string
       (C) privateData/
           (D) userPrivateData/
           -notificationsToken: "9329e48329"
    ...
```

If I want to run a scheduled task that get N random notificationsTokens from users that are not premium, the simplest way to go is to perform a "collectionGroup" query, like this:

```
firestore
    .collectionGroup("privateData")
    .where("random", Math.random() < 0.5 ? "<=" : ">=", randomId)
    .where("premium", "==", false)
    .orderBy("random")
    .orderBy("notificationsToken");
```

But, the "random" and "premium" fields correspond to the parent doc...

Is it possible to get access to a parent doc field in a firestore collectionGroup query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible, the `where()` clauses can only apply to the documents in each `privateData` subcollection.

One solution is to duplicate the fields in the children.